# Question regarding limited number of pages

Tags: errors

I am quite new to latex and have a question that might seem a little silly:

My report that i wrote would have just reached page nr. 10 if compiled. For some reason though the program stops at page 9 and doesnt go any further....

What might be the reason for this issue?

this is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,paper=a4,BCOR=0pt,DIV=14,footinclude=true]{scrartcl}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
... some packages for math etc were left away)
```

Comment: Welcome, there are no silly questions. Just a hint: TeX was designed for book creation, and books are longer than 10 pages. You simply have an error in your code. Please post a [minimal working exampl](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html).

Comment: Take a copy of your code and remove as many things as possible while checking that you still obtain this error. In this way, you can either find yourself what caused it or provide a MWE to SE.

Comment: What is reported in the `.log` file?

Comment: If it stops after page 9 then your file has a command to stop it, most likely `\end{document}` (or `\stop`) any text after that is simply ignored.